# Is there a way to see the requests made using Bruno?

Tags: postman, bruno

I would like to be able to see the request that is sent when executing a request using Bruno. This is visible in Postman. Curious if Bruno has this capability.

I looked around the program and the documentation and didn't seem to find anything on this topic.

Comment: Are you using Bruno as a VSCode extension? If so then the requests should be logged to output.

Comment: @tomredfern no, I'm using it as a standalone program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find the sent request (including the called URI and header fields) in the "Timeline" tab at the right-hand side of Brunos GUI (close to the "Response" tab) - see screenshot attached:

[image]